# Spark convert dataframe to RowMatrix

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe resulted from a sequence of transformations. It looks like the following:

```
id matrixRow
0  [1,2,3]
1  [4,5,6]
2  [7,8,9]
```

each row actually corresponds to a row of a matrix.
How can I convert the matrixRow column of the dataframe to RowMatrix?

Comment: What language are using?

Comment: @Psidom I'm using scala

Comment: When you say matrix, do you mean an array of arrays or a scale-breeze matrix?

Comment: No, it refers to a matrix in the context of algebra.

Comment: OK. So what data structure are you trying to implement the *algebra matrix* in?

Comment: As I mentioned in the example above, the rows of the matrix result from a sequence of transformation from another dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After numerous tries, here's one solution:

```
val rdd = df.rdd.map(
           row => Vectors.dense(row.getAs[Seq[Double]](1).toArray)//get the second column value as Seq[Double], then as Array, then cast to Vector
          )
val row = new RowMatrix(rdd)
```